# Qual a diferença entre * e *|*

Tags: css

Usando `*` encontrarei todos os elementos usando o CSS

mas recentemente encontrei em alguns códigos o uso de  `*|*`

qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem a resposta pra sua pergunta aqui nesse tópico do SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987370/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-css

Mas pra adiantar pra ti. 
`*|*` representa o seletor de "todos os elementos no namespace". De acordo com o W3C, O seletor é dividido em:

`ns|E`

Onde `ns` é o namespace e E é o elemento. Por default, namespaces não são declarados. Então, a não ser que o namespace seja declarado explicitamente, `*|*` e `*` irão selecionar os mesmos elementos.